# How to extract big text from Excel cell in a formatted text with Excel formulas?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007

I have below text in Excel cell:

```
$abcd.$efghijk.$lmn.$op.$qrst.
```

I want above text in following format in Excel cell using Excel formula only:

```
abcd$abcd.efghijk$efghijk.lmn$lmn.op$op.qrst$qrst.
```

Comment: Hi Pallavi, this site expects to see your efforts before helping out. So you have to show us what have you tried so far.

Comment: @ShrivallabhaRedij  I wrote this formula but it gives result of only first string not for second string. ="$" & MID(RC[-1],FIND("$",RC[-1])+1,FIND(".",RC[-1],4)-FIND("$",RC[-1])-1)&"."&MID(RC[-1],FIND("$",RC[-1])+1,FIND(".",RC[-1],4)-FIND("$",RC[-1])-1)                                                                                        It gives result like abcd$abcd. but I need it for all text

Comment: How many such parts are you expecting in a single cell? e.g. In cell A2 if you have data then this formula will do it for you `=CONCATENATE(MID(REPT(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE("."&A2,".",REPT(" ",99)),1*99,99)),2),2,99),".",MID(REPT(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE("."&A2,".",REPT(" ",99)),2*99,99)),2),2,99),".",MID(REPT(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE("."&A2,".",REPT(" ",99)),3*99,99)),2),2,99),".",MID(REPT(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE("."&A2,".",REPT(" ",99)),4*99,99)),2),2,99),".")`

Comment: near about 1000

Comment: @pallavisahane: please copy your code in comments to the question itself, and then delete the comment. The formatting is better in questions, and code is much more readable there.

Comment: It also isn't clear what you are asking. For each pattern beginning with a dollar, do you wish to repeat that without the dollar? What is the logic here?

Comment: `="$" & MID(RC[-1],FIND("$",RC[-1])+1,FIND(".",RC[-1],4)-FIND("$",RC‌​[-1])-1)&"."&MID(RC[‌​-1],FIND("$",RC[-1])‌​+1,FIND(".",RC[-1],4‌​)-FIND("$",RC[-1])-1‌​)` I wrote this formula but i want it for 1000 strings in single cell

Comment: @pallavisahane Formula will not be feasible at all if you mean you have 1000 such items separated by "." in just one cell and you want them to be replicated as you've shown. It will have to be UDF.

Comment: then will Macro better for this??

Comment: Yes. VBA UDF or Macro can handle it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I will suggest based on discussion.

In a general module, insert following code.

```
Public Function RepeatCustom(strInput As String) As String
Dim varInput As Variant
Dim i As Long
If Len(strInput) = 0 Then
    RepeatCustom = ""
Else
    varInput = Split(strInput, ".")
    For i = LBound(varInput) To UBound(varInput)
        RepeatCustom = RepeatCustom & " " & Mid(varInput(i), 2, Len(varInput(i))) & varInput(i)
    Next
    RepeatCustom = Replace(Trim(RepeatCustom), " ", ".") & "."
End If
End Function
```

And then assuming cell containing original data is A2, you can use above UDF:

=RepeatCustom(A2)

Just note that the code is minimum and is based on sample posted.